# Error `can't resolve http ...' when running ng build --prod because of xmlrpc npm package?

Tags: angular, npm, xmlhttprequest, xml-rpc, angular8

I use [xmlrpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlrpc) npm package in angular8 project.

The problem is when trying to build the project it gives an error in not resolving http or https:

> ```
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in ...
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http'
> ```

After investigation these are the lines that produce the problem because angular has its own `HTTPClientModule`. Any ideas please?

```js
var http  = require('http')
  , https = require('https')
  , url   = require('url')
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of npm packages are no longer supported in latest versions of angular CLI now it's built-in Node modules so you need to import these modules manually to do that you should change in 
`node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js`

find

```
node:false
```

replace `false` with your needed packages like that

```
node:{http:true,https:true,url:true}
```

I know this is a workaround and not a reproducible fix but it works

you can make it more dynamic by creating a patch file and run it after npm install 
this should be something like that

```sh
node buildPatch.js
```

buildPatch.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js';

fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/node: false/g, 'node: {http:true,https:true,url:true}');

  fs.writeFile(path, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```